# How to upload the JSON file to BigQuery

Tags: json, google-bigquery

I am trying to upload the JSON file to BigQuery using the data below:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uspun.png)
, I first cover the JSON file to new line delimited JSON using the code below:

```
cat healthrecord.json | jq -c '.[]' > healthrecordNDJSON.json
```

After the code, the new delimited JSON file is shown here:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lxd26.png)
However, when I want to upload the NDJSON file to BigQuery, I get this error:

> Error while reading data, error message: Failed to parse JSON: No active field found.; ParsedString returned false

here is my JSON file below:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1-H3fclfhSvtYS8f51hsnUyPEA1yPmwkr/view?usp=sharing

here is the NDJSON file link:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1zG2JWd1gSEaxC15WpECh7ws_2l-7EWB0/view?usp=sharing

What am I doing wrong here? Please help me correct this! Thx.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT:

As there is only one record the command jq -c '.[]' does not work as a NDjson conversion:
This command changes an array-like json
ex:

```
[
 {
   "id": 1
 }, 
 {
   "id": 2
 },
 {
   "id": 3
 }
]
```

into a file with one element per line (without the enclosing array)

```
{"id": 1},
{"id": 2}, 
{"id": 3}
```

In your case it doesn't work, you just need to format nicely the json into a NDjson.
The following command worked for me:

```
cat healthrecord.json | jq -c . > healthrecordNDJSON.json
```

(You were very close indeed ^^)

---

Have you tried to directly upload healthrecord.json ?

There is only one record in the data you want to upload so I am not sure of the behaviour of " | jq -c '.[]' ". (maybe use instead "jq -c " only).

If this doesn't work may I suggest you actually share the whole json record you want to upload and the command you use to upload it ?

Comment: yes, I have already tried and got the error: Error while reading data, error message: Failed to parse JSON: Unexpected end of string; Unexpected end of string; Expected key. thanks for your advice, Iwill put my JSON file into my answer. can you please have a look?

Comment: hey, I upload the JSON file to google drive, here is the link: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/19-nfL8mo2i_Ig34gQ7NWUxmkzGOQwp_k?usp=sharing

Comment: It seems like a formatting issue in your json. Could you maybe copy-paste it into your question ?

Comment: I put the json file link in my question, can you please have a look?

Comment: Ok, I understand why you didn't put in the body of your question ^^

Comment: Glad to hear that! ^^
I think you just need to flag the question as "solved" to close the issue  ;)